# Windows update changes voltage levels causing hardware damage?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-update, physical-damage

I work for a large company in IT.   There is a sensitive project that requires unique and special cfast hard drives from Israel which cost a fortune.  The HDDs are super hardened (or at least they claim they are).  The vendor has a Windows 10 RTM image running on it.  They say the OS is "hardened" and they even prevent Windows updates from being installed.  Their reason is that a Windows Update could possibly cause a voltage change connected to the special hard drives.  Is this true?  Can a Windows update cause any variation of Voltage levels in the hardware?

Comment: "Can a Windows update cause any variation of Voltage levels in the hardware?" I don't see how, that is controlled by the bios and not Windows.

Comment: There's probably some other real reason that they don't want to discuss.

Comment: Zero voltage changes on the machines here with the newest Windows Updates including Insider to V21354.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Update could change the Power Plan and that might change how the
CPU load is handled, which also changes how core voltage is working.
Also, changes to core API could cause the API to behave differently as
regarding control of the CPU voltage.

Examples found on the internet:

[**KB4093118 disables voltage control**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/kb4093118-disables-voltage-control/a1edfd1a-ba7b-48e3-9004-ffbbf1e66abc?auth=1):

> So it seems that KB4093118 breaks some compatibility in the CPU voltage control API.

[**Microsoft windows 10 update versions is responsible to surge high voltage +12V, +5V , +3.3V...**](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/microsoft-windows-10-update-versions-is-responsible-to-surge-high-voltage-12v-5v-3-3v.239053/):

> No reason to say faulty motherboard , many users find same issue on
> them pc
>
> I also changed smps (PSU), update bios, clear coms,change comes
> battery, remove connected devices , windows clean installation etc but
> nothing happened

Conclusion: Don't presume that the manufacturers are wrong.

Super fast must mean very delicate adjustments for gaining microseconds
here and there, so unforeseen changes may throw off the algorithms,
causing performance issues.